# Clearing std::vector of pointers with std::unary_function

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, destructor, unary-function

In his "Effective STL" Meyers show how to clean vector of pointers correctly (`std::vector::clear` deletes only his pointers, and not the memory they occupy).

So he advices before the call to `clear` use `for_each` with unary_function which calls object destructor:

```
template<typename T> struct DeleteMyObject2: public std::unary_function<const T*, void>
{
    void operator()(const T* ptr);
};

template<> struct DeleteMyObject2<algotest::ImageSelection>
{
   void operator()(const algotest::ImageSelection* ptr)
   {
       delete ptr;
       ptr=0; // this was added by me 
   }
};

void std_clearing_pointers()
{
   std::vector<ImageSelection*> vec;
   vec.reserve(5);
   for(int i=0; i<5; ++i)
       vec.insert(vec.begin(), new ImageSelection());

   std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), DeleteMyObject2<ImageSelection>());

   // HERE elements of vec are not NULL !!! 
   vec.clear();
}
```

In the book `DeleteMyObject2` was called without parentheses, it doesn't compile (**question1**: why? was Standard changed?):

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), DeleteMyObject2<ImageSelection>);
```

Anyway, it compiles if call `operator()` for `DeleteMyObject2`, but before `vec.clear()` objects in vector are not NULL's. I  suppose that as STL containers copy their elements all the time, `ImageSelection` pointer is passed by value, so everything is okay (**question2**: am I correct?).

I tried passing pointer by ref, now objects are NULLs after `for_each`, and I feel safer.

```
template<> struct DeleteMyObject1<algotest::ImageSelection>
{
    void operator()(algotest::ImageSelection*& ptr)
    {
        delete ptr;
        ptr=0;
    }
 };
```

**question3**: is `DeleteMyObject2` more preferable than `DeleteMyObject1` because it hasn't unnecessary assignments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Effective STL came out, there are shorter and more readable ways to do this. For example, you can now write

```
vector<int *> a{new int{1}, new int{2}};
for_each(begin(a), end(a), [](int *p){delete p;});
```

where `[](int *p){delete p;}` is an [lambda or, anonymous, function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) saying to `delete` any `p`, in much shorter code than either of the classes in your question.

As an aside, you might also want to consider a `vector` of smart pointers (e.g., `vector<shared_ptr<int>>` for a vector of pointers to integers). Explicit code to deallocate resources, is error prone.

As for your questions:

1. The class *should* appear with parentheses, with which you indicate you want a (default-constructed) object of this class. The function expects an object, not a class.
2. It is fine to pass pointers by value (in this case).